# Arrays of strings in Managed C++

Tags: c++, arrays, managed, managed-c++

I'm trying to write an application in Managed C++, but I cannot work out how to declare an array of strings.

> String^ linet[];

throws an error

> 'System::String ^' : a native array cannot contain this managed type

So I suppose there's a different way to do this for managed data types. What exactly is it?

Comment: Just a little nitpick: While Managed C++ & C++/CLI will to my knowledge be compiled into the same code, they're actually two distinct languages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you really mean Managed C++? Not C++/CLI?

Assuming you're actually using C++/CLI (because of the error message you posted), there are two ways to do this:

```
array<String^>^ managedArray = gcnew array<String^>(10);
```

will create a managed array, i.e. the same type as string[] in C#.

```
gcroot<String^>[] unmanagedArray;
```

will create an unmanaged C++ array (I've never actually tried this with arrays - it works well with stl containers, so it should work here, too).

Comment: How's that work when calling String->Split() (array of strings version)?

Comment: @user645280 - array<String^>^ sa = str->Split(gcnew array<String^>{"one","two"}, StringSplitOptions::None);
You need to specify the StringSplitOptions when using spit strings.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/cppcliarrays.aspx

That should have all the answers you need :)

When working with Managed C++ (aka. C++/CLI aka. C++/CLR) you need to consider your variable types in everything you do. Any "managed" type (basically, everything that derives from System::Object) can only be used in a managed context. A standard C++ array basically creates a fixed-size memory-block on the heap, with sizeof(type) x NumberOfItems bytes, and then iterates through this. A managed type can not be guarenteed to stay the same place on the heap as it originally was, which is why you can't do that :)

Comment: Just a little nitpick: While Managed C++ & C++/CLI will to my knowledge be compiled into the same code, they're actually two distinct languages.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B "...These new extensions were designated C++/CLI and included in Microsoft Visual Studio 2005.[1] The term Managed C++ and the extensions it refers to are thus deprecated and superseded by the new extensions...." - So yeah, you are absolutely correct.

Comment: I only mentioned it because Managed C++ doesn't use handles (managed pointers, declared as `type^`), but C++/CLI does.  ...Now that I think about it, the person who asked the question got the two mixed up, too.

Answer (score 1):

You use a collection class from .Net. For [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

```
List<String^>^ dinosaurs = gcnew List<String^>();
```