# How to declare array of handel?

Tags: c++, .net, arrays, collections, c++-cli

I want to declare an array of handel as the following code:

```
using namespace System::Drawing;
ref class B 
{
    Bitmap^ b[];

    B()
    {
        b = new Bitmap^[10];
    }
};
```

But it threw error when compiling

```
error C2728: 'System::Drawing::Bitmap ^' : a native array cannot contain this managed type
error C4368: cannot define 'b' as a member of managed 'B': mixed types are not supported
error C2728: 'System::Drawing::Bitmap ^' : a native array cannot contain this managed type
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'System::Drawing::Bitmap ^*' to 'System::Drawing::Bitmap ^[]'
```

Someone can tell me the correctly way to declare an array of handel?

Many thanks!

T&TGroup

Comment: I'd rather have an array of Mozart than of Handel. Do you mean handle?

Comment: String handelsWorks[] = { "Nero", "Almira", "Messiah" } :) Just a joke.

Comment: Also I suggest just googling your first error to see the problem.  You will be lead to the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995434/arrays-of-strings-in-managed-c

Comment: You cannot store managed object references in an unmanaged array.  The garbage collector won't be able to find them back.  Use the *array* keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `gcnew` <strike>since this a .Net array, not a C++ array</strike> since this is an array of a managed type, not an array of a native type. I don't have a compiler handy to test this code, but I believe this would be the way to do it.

```
using namespace System::Drawing;
ref class B 
{
private:
    array<Bitmap^>^ b;

public:
    B()
    {
        b = gcnew array<Bitmap^>(10);
    }
};
```

Comment: needs to be `array<Bitmap^>^ b;`

Comment: @crashmstr Good catch. I figured posting that untested I was bound to hit a couple of those type of things. It is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a generic collection type instead of an array.

Not sure what a handel is, though.